# On calling ctx.bumps.get("mint_account"), failing with error method `get` not found for this struct

Tags: solana-program, anchor-lang, token-2022, anchor-spl

Hi I am trying to call `ctx.bumps.get("mint_account")` on

```
#[derive(Accounts)]
#[instruction(params: CreateTokenParams)] pub struct CreateToken<'info> {
    /// CHECK: New Metaplex Account being created
    #[account(mut)]
    pub metadata: UncheckedAccount<'info>,

    #[account(
        init,
        seeds = [CONFIG_TAG],
        bump,
        payer = authority,
        space = std::mem::size_of::<TokenConfiguration>() + 8
    )]
    pub config: Box<Account<'info, TokenConfiguration>>,

    #[account(
        init,
        seeds = [b"<some phrase>"],
        bump,
        payer = authority,
        mint::decimals = 0,
        mint::authority = authority,
        mint::freeze_authority = authority,
    )]
    pub mint_account: Box<InterfaceAccount<'info, Mint>>,

    #[account(mut)]
    pub authority: Signer<'info>,

    pub rent: Sysvar<'info, Rent>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
    pub token_program: Program<'info, Token2022>,

    /// CHECK: account constraint checked in account trait
    #[account(address = mpl_token_metadata::ID)]
    pub token_metadata_program: UncheckedAccount<'info>, }
```

but it is failing with below error
[image]

What is wrong with this, why this is failing with get() method not found for CreateTokenBumps

I have also tried CreateTokenBumps but still getting the same error.

Comment: I faced the same issue and I resolved issue using this answer. it is very really helpful for me, thank you very much

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're using anchor-lang 0.29 (check the Cargo.toml file), the syntax for getting the bump has been updated.

Try using:

```
ctx.bumps.mint_account
```

Comment: thanks worked for me, I was using anchor-lang 0.29 only